# How can I monitor every single request passing through my VPN in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, openvpn

I have successfully created Open vpn on AWS using [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-i2JBtG4FE) blog.
But i am not able to find any blog to monitor this requests.

For eg. searched google, opened stackoverflow with Json data in requests. any request which is being passed from my device.
Please help me with this if it is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your VPN aws instance and write `ifconfig`. There you should see the OpenVPN Network interface, it will probably be `tun0` or similar.

Then you can record all your VPN traffic using `tcpdump -i tun0` or any other network monitoring tool.